# How to set Image Properly in table view cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am developing simple tableview application and as shown into screen shot the Images are not placed from left. I mean it doesn't touch left border.

[image]

code for my Simple table view is :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var iteams : [String] = ["Egg Benedict", "Mushroom Risotto", "Full Breakfast", "Hamburger", "Ham and Egg Sandwich", "Creme Brelee", "White Chocolate Donut", "Starbucks Coffee", "Vegetable Curry", "Instant Noodle with Egg", "Noodle with BBQ Pork", "Japanese Noodle with Pork", "Green Tea", "Thai Shrimp Cake", "Angry Birds Cake", "Ham and Cheese Panini"]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   // to get the class use the class name followed by .self
    self.TableViewData.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
}

@IBOutlet var TableViewData: UITableView!

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

    return self.iteams.count

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    // Create the cell
    var cell : UITableViewCell = self.TableViewData.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.iteams[indexPath.row]
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "creme_brelee.jpg")
    return cell


}
```

}

please tell me any solution for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why dont u create custom tableview cell??

Comment: create one custom cell and set frame for label and imageview

Comment: sorry, i am new to swift.. i know very well abt old process where we create tableview cell class and add label and imageview objects as properties and in cellforrowatindexpath create object of tableviewcll and set text and image to the properties.and also set frame for these two in custom  tableview cell class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26366456/custom-table-cell-view-with-xib-throwing-exception-on-ios-8

Comment: I have to change many things in code because its very different in swift compare to objective-C.

Comment: self.TableViewData.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell. How do you make a "Cell" contains a uiimageview and a uilabel?

Comment: This code works for it :cell.textLabel?.text = self.iteams[indexPath.row]
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "creme_brelee.jpg")